# What is the fastest way to generate a random integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, random, floating-point, integer

Normally this is how you get a random number in javascript.

```
Math.random();
```

However, this method seems to be inefficient when it comes to generating random integers.

Firstly, the random function has to generate a random decimal, like *`0.1036098338663578`*, then it has to be multiplied to a suitable range (*`10.464593220502138`*). Finally, the floor function subtracts the decimals to produce the result (which in this case, *`10`*).

```
var random_integer = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
```

Is there a faster way to generate random integers in javascript?

### Edit1:

I am using this for creating a canvas HTML5 game. The FPS is about 50, and my code is pretty optimized, apart from generating a random number.

Comment: "However this method seems inefficient " - have you measured it?

Comment: How fast do you need it to be?  With the code above I can get 10M random numbers in 500ms on my old laptop.

Comment: In most languages, you'd want a random number generator by seeding and mod'ing against some prime. In JavaScript, however, there is more overhead in the evaluation of the language than in the overhead of calls to something like Math.random() meaning that native calls are almost always faster than anything you can implement.

Comment: Try saving the canvas width in a var rather than accessing it everytime. It may be that simple.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This code is faster... to type.

```
var random_integer = Math.random()*101|0;
```

It won't work right for huge numbers though.

(and it doesn't run any faster, at least not in chrome.)

You could achieve a much faster speed during the game if you generate the random numbers beforehand, though.

```
for (var i=1e6, lookupTable=[]; i--;) {
  lookupTable.push(Math.random()*101|0);
}
function lookup() {
  return ++i >= lookupTable.length ? lookupTable[i=0] : lookupTable[i];
}
```

`lookup` will rotate through an array with a million random integers. It is [much faster](http://jsperf.com/floor-or-or) than calling `random` and `floor` (of course, there is a "loading time" penalty up front from generating the lookup table).

Comment: It runs significantly faster in almost everything but chrome

Comment: hmm, interesting. I usually do this because I'm lazy and it's easier to read.

Comment: @cwolves I just ran it in firefox with the same results... http://jsperf.com/floor-or-or

Comment: @user824294 add it to the jsperf and see :)

Comment: @Rasu Don't pre allocate the array. you can achieve 1000x faster for a very large array :)

Comment: @Ghominejad the problem with Rasu's edit is it's still pushing things onto the array even though it was pre-allocated. I wonder how pre-allocating it would help performance if the assignments were done properly in the loop? Rolling back Rasu's edit for now.

Comment: Arrays have an "implementation determined size" in which they become less efficient - not to mention the cost of creating the array vs generating values directly. I would *not* pregenerate (or even recommend the generation of) such a [large] array, unless such shows a relevant performance improvement *in the actual usage* or is required for other purposes.

Comment: @DaggNabbit In node js it took more than 50 seconds then i had to stop it! because node have to change the default type of the array elements at runtime for million items. but generating 1 million items without pre-allocation took about 100ms! because it pre-allocates itself by type of the first value. you can achieve even more performance by pre-allocating [Typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) in javascript.

Comment: @user2864740 I agree that in general this should not be necessary, but the OP claims that the RNG is a bottleneck in this case, and pre-generating the random numbers does seem to help significantly in most versions of most browsers. I assume using a seeded PRNG (which most games would probably want to do) would be significantly slower than Math.random, but the lookup time would of course be the same. Do you know of a better way to address this?

Comment: I'd first make sure that "this method seems to be inefficient" is accurate / relevant. A simple [LCG](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Karl_Entacher/publication/228386019_Bad_subsequences_of_well-known_linear_congruential_pseudorandom_number_generators/links/00b4952247ee06caab000000.pdf) PRNG implementations takes "inconsequential time" - assuming it is called only as relevant - compared to everything else that has to occur in a game that does .. game stuff. If these PRNGs are only every used once then the array can "move the work" but won't reduce the overall cycles consumed.

Comment: Thats a lot of wasted storage space though.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid floating point calculation then you can do that by writing your own pseudo random number generator. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pseudorandom_number_generators) is a list of well known pseudo random number generators (PRNG). [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is the easiest one to implement and probably most effective in terms of performance too. However, you will need to understand the [theory behind PRNGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) well enough to write an effective one. That might not be worth of effort though. The JS implementation should be effective enough. At the end there is a high possibility that you will find `Math.random()` is running faster than your code.

Answer (score 2):

Heres what I use:

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
```

An example of how this would be used would be

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
if(getRandomInt(420) == 69){
console.log("nice")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i mostly use

```
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random((number you'd like to be minimum, (number you'd like to be maximum) * (number you'd like to be maximum);
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of using comments in snippets?

Comment: `Math.random() * (max - min) + min`?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easier or shorter way.  You can create a function if you need to do it multiple times, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
const getRandomInt = (base = 10) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * base)
}
```

Comment: This is a more 2017-appropriate method than the previous answers

Comment: This is a more "let's just ignore that Dagg Nabbit has already posted almost the exact same answer" method than the previous answers. Although your code "works", it is a near duplication of Dagg Nabbit's answer. In such a case as this, I would recommend making an edit suggested to his answer instead of posting it as your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your way is the right way to retrive a random integer in javascript, don't worry about performance it will run fast.

Answer (score -1):

This is the shortest one-liner Random Number Generator code

```
rnd=(a,b)=>~~(Math.random()*(b-a))+a
```

How To Use: rnd(min,max)
Example   : rnd(10,100)