# How does x|0 floor the number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, integer, floor

In the accepted answer on my earlier question
( [What is the fastest way to generate a random integer in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775962/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-javascript) ), I was wondering how a number loses its decimals via the symbol `|`
.

For example:

```
var x = 5.12042;
x = x|0;
```

How does that floor the number to `5`?

Some more examples:

```
console.log( 104.249834 | 0 ); //104
console.log( 9.999999 | 0 );   // 9
```

Comment: You should be aware that using bitwise operators will limit you to 32-bit signed integers. `((Math.pow(2,32)/2)-1)|0; // 2147483647` Remove the `-1` and you'll not get the desired result. `((Math.pow(2,32)/2))|0; // -2147483648`

Comment: Interesting. That's probably the reason that this function is slightly faster than the `Math.floor(x)` function. http://jsperf.com/floor-or-or

Comment: it is not actually 'flooring', try with `-1.23` to see what happens

Comment: Yes, truncating is the correct term in this case. @ajax333221

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because, according to the ECMAScript specifications, bitwise operators call `ToInt32` on each expression to be evaluated.

See [11.10 Binary Bitwise Operators](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.10):

> The production `A : A @B`, where `@` is one of the bitwise operators in
> the productions above, is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate `A`.
> 2. Call `GetValue(Result(1))`.
> 3. Evaluate `B`.
> 4. Call `GetValue(Result(3))`.
> 5. **Call `ToInt32(Result(2)).`**
> 6. **Call `ToInt32(Result(4)).`**
> 7. Apply the bitwise operator `@` to `Result(5)` and `Result(6)`. *The result is a signed 32 bit integer*.
> 8. Return `Result(7)`.

Answer (score 5):

Bitwise operators convert their arguments to integers (see http://es5.github.com/#x9.5).
Most languages *I know* don't support this type of conversion:

```
    $ python -c "1.0|0"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'int'

    $ ruby -e '1.0|0'
    -e:1:in `': undefined method `|' for 1.0:Float (NoMethodError)

    $ echo "int main(){1.0|0;}" | gcc -xc -
    : In function ‘main’:
    :1: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘double’ and ‘int’)
```

Comment: `s/Most (.*?) don't/Strongly typed \1 generally don't/` (This is, however, very language-dependent.)

Answer (score 2):

When doing a `floor`, although it would be possible to convert the argument to an integer, this is not what most languages would do because the original type is a floating-point number.

A better way to do it while preserving the data type is to go to `exponent` digits into the `mantissa` and zero the remaining bits.

If you're interested you can take a look at the [IEEE spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) for floating point numbers.