# How to convert from unsigned to 2's complement in js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to convert binary unsigned number to two's complement with javascript:

```
function bin_input_to_num(input) // 2 bit, input is string
{
    return ~Number('0b' + input) + '0b01'; // using ES6
}

console.log(bin_input_to_num('11'));  // actual: -3, expected: -1
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

(edit: I have carefully read through the [marked possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337406/7299313) question and answers, and it doesn't resolve my issue here)

Comment: You mean, the input is a string of 1s and 0s?

Comment: You say that `11` is unsigned, so how would that be equal to anything else than `3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Tilde & Two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337360/javascript-tilde-twos-complement)

Comment: @ChrisG I am working with 2 bits in the program as commented. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Bergi I'm sorry it's not clear to me what you are saying.

Comment: In that case: `return Number('0b' + input) - 4; // using ES6
`

Comment: @ChrisG That wouldn't work, (eg: '00')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two's complement, you first need to decide whether the number is complemented or not. Since all parsing functions work with a minus instead of two's complement representation, we need to parse a positive/unsigned number and do some fiddling. If the input is not complemented (starts with `0`), it's trivial, otherwise we have three choices:

- complement the bit string, parse to a number, complement the number back to the intended value:

  ```
  console.assert(input.length == 2);
  console.assert(input[0] == '1');
  const compl = input.replace(/[01]/g, function(d){return +!+d;});
  const num = parseInt(compl, 2); // or Number('0b' + compl);
  return ~num; // or -(num + 1) or -num-1
  ```
- extend to 32 bit, parse to a number, and cast to a signed 32 bit number with the builtin bitwise operators:

  ```
  console.assert(input.length == 2)
  console.assert(input[0] == '1');
  const input32 = "1".repeat(30)+input;
  const num = parseInt(input32, 2); // or Number('0b' + input32);
  return num >> 0; // or ~~num or num | 0
  ```
- implement the wrap-around by subtraction (which can be combined with the non-complement case to a modulo operation to avoid branching):

  ```
  console.assert(input.length == 2);
  console.assert(input[0] == '1');
  const num = parseInt(input, 2); // or Number('0b' + input);
  return num - 4; // 2²
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the longer explanation. I don't understand the need for this extra step in method 2: `return num >> 0;` (double bit flips?) after integer has been parsed. Also, I am still not sure why my original code doesn't work.

Comment: It takes the integer (which is still positive - uint32) and casts it to a signed integer (int32) by using a bitwise operator that "does nothing".

Comment: How is that possible? (I really appreciate the effort to help me, but now I'm completely lost.)

Comment: It's a property of all the bitwise operators. They cast all numbers they are working on from the standard 64 bit floating point representation to 32 bit integers. [It's a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9049677/1048572). Don't use it if you're not comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check if it's in the negative range, then adjust accordingly? Something like this:

```js
const compliment8bit = number => number < 128 ? number : -(256 - number);
```