# Javascript parseInteger() to Int32?

Tags: javascript, integer

I'm trying to convert an integer to Int32 in Javascript (similar to how you'd convert a string to an integer using parseInteger()), however I cannot find the appropriate method. How can I do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what context do you require this.  Is it for some IPC protocol, or just for display purposes.  Generally speaking in JS an integer is just a number, like float is just a number.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049677/how-does-x0-floor-the-number-in-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+convert+32+bit+integer

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's number type is IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point; it doesn't have an integer type except temporarily during some math operations or as part of a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) (`Int32Array`, for instance, or a `Uint32Array` if you mean unsigned). So you have two options:

1. Ensure that the number has a value that fits in a 32-bit int, even though it's still a number (floating point double). One way to do that is to do a bitwise OR operation with the value `0`, because the bitwise operations in JavaScript convert their operands to 32-bit integers before doing the operation:

   `| 0` does a signed conversion using the specification's [`ToInt32` operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toint32):

   ```
   value = value | 0;
   // Use `value`...
   ```

   With that, `-5` becomes `-5`. `123456789123` becomes `-1097262461` (yes, negative).

   or `>>> 0` does an unsigned conversion using the spec's [`ToUint32`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-touint32):

   ```
   value = value >>> 0;
   // Use `value`...
   ```

   The latter converts to *unsigned* 32-bit int. `-5` becomes `4294967291`, `123456789123` becomes `3197704835`.
2. Use an `Int32Array` or `Uint32Array`:

   ```
   const a = new Int32Array(1); // Or use Uint32Array for unsigned
   a[0] = value;
   // Use `a[0]`...
   ```

   `Int32Array` uses `ToInt32`, `Uint32Array` uses `ToUint32`.

   Note that any time you *use* `a[0]`, it will be converted back to a standard number (floating point double), but if you use the array, depending on what you use it for, it will get used as-is.

Note that there's a method that may seem like it's for doing this, but isn't: `Math.fround`. That doesn't convert to 32-bit int, it converts to 32-bit **float** (IEEE-754 **single**-precision floating point). So it isn't useful for this.

Comment: @Jayce444 returns a float preserving the decimal part. `Math.fround(5.05); // -> 5.050000190734863`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just add it to your answer

Comment: @VLAZ - Thanks, yeah, was just refreshing myself on it from the spec on it and said "Where's the integer bit of this process?" :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I cheated and just looked at the demo at the top of the MDN page :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way I found is using bitwise not `~`.

This is the description from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT#description):

> The operands are converted to 32-bit integers and expressed by a series of bits (zeroes and ones).

So you can just type double `~` to convert your numbers. Here's some examples:

```js
~~1 // 1
~~-1 // -1
~~5.05 // 5
~~-5.05 // -5
~~2147483647 // 2147483647
~~2147483648 // -2147483648
~~Math.pow(2, 32) // 0
```

Comment: All of the bitwise operations convert to 32-bit integer. So any operation that *logically* doesn't change the number, will result in truncating the value to a 32-bit. So, NOT NOT: `~~n`; OR: `n | 0`; AND `n & 1`; Right shift`n >> 0`; Left shift: `n << 0`.