# Efficient get random whole number between two intervals

Tags: javascript

I use this normally.

```
var min = 0;
var max = 1;

console.log(Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min) + min)));
```

It works fine and dandy, but I can't get over thinking that this may be an expensive way of producing this result, does anyone know of a more efficient way?

Or *is* this the most efficient way?

Comment: I don't know of any better ways, all implementations I've come across do the same

Comment: This guy appears to be looking for the same thing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775962/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-javascript

Comment: Have you created a performance test with http://jsperf.com?

Comment: @DasBeasto Thanks man! This can be marked as duplicate is someone would please!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this approach also

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min
```

This will work efficiently.

Comment: This isn't going to work. Your max here is a range

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much as efficient as it gets.

You could create a function which will at least clean up your code a bit:

Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

```
// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```